# What is a better approach to prototype for multiple types

Tags: javascript, function

Ignoring the fact that this is implemented by ***many*** frameworks..

What is the best way to prototype for multiple object types.

For example, Should I write:

```
Element.prototype.bind = function(eventType, fn) {
    this.addEventListener(eventType, fn, false);
};
NodeList.prototype.bind = function(eventType, fn) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        this[i].addEventListener(eventType, fn, false);
    }
};
```

or

```
Object.prototype.bind = function(eventType, fn) {
    if (this instanceof Element) {
        this.addEventListener(eventType, fn, false);
    } else if (this instanceof NodeList) {
        for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
            this[i].addEventListener(eventType, fn, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://jsperf.com/prototype-methods Ok, so I have found that the first method is better performance, and I would assume it also offers less chance of conflicts?

Comment: Yeah its also neater and easier to read IMHO ... if you want the same function on multiple types then the code is MUCH cleaner. Imagine `this instanceof Element || this instanceof OtherType || ... ` :O

Comment: The best place for this is probably SO. Could you add some context? What problems did you encounter that caused you to ask this?

Comment: None, I just plan on writing a lot of code *like* this and before I do I wanted to know what the better approach is.

Comment: It may get killed here too without some hand-holding. We need to know _what_ the intent is. What is confusing about the strategy? What is it you are uncomfortable with.

Comment: You should never prototype Object. It will mess up for(in) loops.

Comment: @Marshall not well defended loops

Comment: I understand the downfalls of extending `Object.prototype`, believe me there is enough people out there screaming on about it to learn. However it is also understood that in certain cases it is required (this is not one of them). My question is more generic, do I encapsulate it all in a single function and separate logic depending on the type? Or (like the answer below) so I write separate functions with their own logic (which may chain together to form a greater whole).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Big* red flag: **never** extend `Object.prototype`!  It breaks `for (x in y)` (or at least people's expectations of how it works).

In the general case, however, it's better to extend the individual types' prototypes rather than try to find a common base and perform reflection checks.  There are two basic reasons to do this.

First, JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, so you should generally prefer duck typing and basic inheritance over `instanceof` and reflection.  In many cases, there is a small performance benefit, but mainly this is so you don't spend time fighting the language.

Second, this type of method switching implies connections between the switched methods which do not necessarily exist.  In your sample code, this can be seen in the `NodeList` version.  Conceptually, a list shouldn't be binding anything; if it has a `bind` method, it should simply translate into calling the `bind` method on each of its elements.  This ensures that if any extra steps need added to binding in the future (say, workarounds for old, non-DOM-conforming browsers…), you only need to do so in one place.

But looking at it in terms of type switching in the "same function" gives the false impression that both `Element.bind` and `NodeList.bind` should work the same way — by calling `addEventListener`.  Here's how I'd implement it:

```
Element.prototype.bind = function(eventType, fn) {
    this.addEventListener(eventType, fn, false);
};

NodeList.prototype.bind = function(eventType, fn) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        this[i].bind(eventType, fn);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thankyou, you are the first person to attempt this without getting hung up on the fact I was extending `Object.prototype`. I will start with *I understand the implications of doing this, but I appreciate the warning*. Everything else in your answer is exactly the information I was looking for.